# UILabel: 2 lines text shrinking

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

By design (!) I have two lines title text which I cannot break:

```
JustWord
VeryLongWordWithoutSpaces
```

On big iPhones (6 and 6 Plus) text works great,
but when I test on smaller iPhone (5 or less) it looks like:

```
JustWord
VeryLongWordWi...
```

I cannot find a way how to shrink the text in UILabel.
Cutting and truncating are not possible in my situation.

**Requirements:**
Auto Layout, no Storyboards, Swift 2.0, iOS 8.0+

Comment: Have you tried setting `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:` to true on the label?

Comment: Yes it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth: property for UIlabel. I have tried this and font is setting in one line and font size is automatically adjust.

Answer (score 1):

The two principal ways to do this are to set a minimum font size or a minimum font scale.